# Is there any way to restart the Debezium connector automatically in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, debezium

I am using [Debezium Sql Server Connector for Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/debezium-sqlserver-component.html) to replicate changes from one database to another.

```
@Configuration
class DebeziumRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("debezium-sqlserver:iwdcamel" +
                "?databaseServerName=iwdcamel" +
                "&databaseHostname=localhost" +
                "&databasePort=1433" +
                "&databaseDbname=MyDB" +
                "&databaseUser=sa" +
                "&databasePassword=MyPassword" +
                "&tableWhitelist=dbo.MyTable" +
                "&offsetStorageFileName=./offset-file.dat" +
                "&databaseHistoryFileFilename=./history-file.dat")
            .choice()
                ...
            .end();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, except that when for some reason the database or network goes down, the connector stop and won't start again, even if the database recovers in a few seconds.

```
io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine: Error while trying to run connector class 'io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector'

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server no devolvió una respuesta. Se ha cerrado la conexión.
```

**Is there any way to restart the *Debezium* connector automatically?**, or at least...

**Is there any way to check the status of connector periodically and restart if needed?**

Any idea is welcome...